# Change the size of a section when clicked

Tags: html, css

Lately I've been struggling with this html-problem and hope someone could help.
So I am trying to create a section that increases in size when it is clicked on. In the increased version of the section I want to include some links to different pages.

I have tried using focus but the problem with that is that when I click on the links I want to include the focus method is called upon and the section goes back to the original size instead of following the link.
A similar method that changes the size permanently would solve that problem so that the section doesn't shrink as soon as I click elsewhere on the page.
So far my code looks like this:

```css
section {
  background-color: rgb(153, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

 :focus {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 75px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F7BBB1;
}

 :focus .text {
  color: #000000;
}

 :focus .title {
  color: #990000;
  font-size: 1.266rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 75px;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <?php include ('header.php'); ?>
</div>
<main>
  <h2>Test Sections</h2>
  <p> Click </p>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <section tabindex="0">
      <span class="title">
                Demo #1
              </span>
      <span class="text">
              <a href="#">Test</a>
              </span>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</footer>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using `<summary>` and `<details>`

Comment: Shooting from the hip here; would it work to apply z-index to your section and the links, so that the links have a higher z-index than the section?

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing the `:focus-within` to keep the `<section>` with the CSS you want when the link inside is focused. `:focus-within` selects an element if that element contains any children that have :focus

```css
section {
  background-color: rgb(153, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

 section:focus,
 section:focus-within {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F7BBB1;
}

 section:focus .text,
 section:focus-within .text {
  color: #000000;
}

 section:focus .title,
 section:focus-within .title {
  color: #990000;
  font-size: 1.266rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 75px;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <?php include ('header.php'); ?>
</div>
<main>
  <h2>Test Sections</h2>
  <p> Click </p>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <section tabindex="0">
      <span class="title">
                Demo #1
              </span>
      <span class="text">
              <a href="#">Test</a>
              </span>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</footer>
```